# what do you call someone who always wants to dress up nicely

Tags: single-word-requests

what do you call someone who always wants to dress up nicely.
I mean like little girls that adore their lovely little dresses and such.

Answer (score 1):

[**Fashion plate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fashion%20plate): a person who dresses in the latest fashions

Answer (score -1):

Consider **prim**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/prim)

> to dress primly:  Prim means polite, straight-laced, even twee. Many
>   characters in Jane Austen novels are prim and proper. Clothes can be prim, too!!!

As in:

> Many little girls adore dressing **primly** in their lovely little dresses
>   and such.

Comment: 'Prim' doesn't mean 'liking to dress nicely', it means, as you say, strait-laced or correct. 'Dressy' would be a possibility.

Comment: @KateBunting. straight from the same reference:  **Clothes can be prim, too.**